# If - Else in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I hope someone can steer me in the right direction in terms on how to solve this problem using Kotlin. I'm a beginner in this language and never learned Java so all of this is very confusing.

Here is the problem: Write a function that compares and accepts two numbers ( x and y). If x is less than y return 1, if x>y return -1. Else return 0 .

This is what I have so far but i know for certain its far from working

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    println("Enter Integer Input  X: ")
    val x = Integer

    return when(x) {
       x > y -> -1
       x<y -> 1


 }

   println("Enter Integer Y: ")

   val y = Integer

    return when(y) {
       x > y -> -1
       x<y -> 1
```

Comment: What do you want to retrurn? main function never return anything, you might be printing it. x should be `val x = readLline().toInt()`. When should be `when(x) {...}.let{ println(it) }` to print the value

Comment: Oh I see where my line of thinking was wrong. I Thought I had to evaluate two separate inputs and receive two different outputs. I completely ignored the compare portion. I am very grateful for the help and advice. Thanks!

Comment: @AnimeshSahu --> I was following another tutorial from a website but from what i know now i was not looking at a correct example for what i needed. I needed to compare two values and output one value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) object to read from the console. And after reading both the values you can compare and output them.

```
fun main() {
    val input = Scanner(System.`in`)
    println("Enter Integer Input  X: ")
    val x = input.nextInt()
    println("Enter Integer Input  Y: ")
    val y = input.nextInt()

    println(compareInt(x,y));
}

fun compareInt(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
    return when {
        x == y -> 0;
        x > y -> -1;
        else -> 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a little more kotliny if you write `compareInt(...) = when { ...`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do if you just want a function that does what you described:

```
fun test(x:Int,y:Int ): Int{
    var result =if ( x > y){
        -1
    }
    else if( x < y){
        1
    }
    else{
        0
    }
    return result
}
```

However, if you want to read from the command line and print to the user you can do this:

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main() {

    // create a scanner object which can read from console. 
    val reader = Scanner(System.`in`)
    print("Enter any number x: ")
    // read the next Int from console
    var x = reader.nextInt()
    print("Enter any number y: ")

    var y = reader.nextInt()
    var result =if ( x > y){
        -1
    }
    else if( x < y){
         1
    }
    else{
       0
    }
    println(result)

}
```